# Do not allow the robot to plan in unknow region for navigation. Parameters to set apart from allow_unknown

Tags: navigation, move-base, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I want to make sure that the robot does not plan through the unknow regions of the map.
The map looks as follows:

[image: image description]

I have set the allow unknown parameter in "base_global_planner_param.yaml" as follows:

```
NavfnROS:
  allow_unknown: false
```

and also set the track unknow region parameter in

```
global_costmap:
  map_type: costmap
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  track_unknown_space: true
  unknown_cost_value: 0
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
```

It still plans a path as shown in above image. I have also played with unknown_cost_value parameter, (both 0 and 255), and still no avail.

The objective is to make sure that the robot does not plan apart from a specific region. I intended to edit the map so that i make all the regions grey where i do not want to plan them.

I use a preloaded map and not a live map from gmapping.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210358/do-not-allow-the-robot-to-plan-in-unknow-region-for-navigation.-parameters-to-set-apart-from-allow_unknown/) by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2015-06-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2015-06-04**:
Which version of ROS?

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2015-06-08**:
Currently using ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo. I think I've solved the issue, but would you mind checking out my post for a follow up question and confirm that the fix was done properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Turns out it was a misuse of using the clear cost map service on my end which was causing the path planning issue. Adding the "base_global_plannar_params.yaml" file with "allow_unknown: false" did fix the problem. If someone can confirm this was the proper fix, please let me know.

---

Originally posted by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) with karma: 447 on 2015-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-14**:
That question is completely different from the first question; you should post it as a new question.  I think the general rules of ROS Answers is to not post follow up questions in the answers.

**Comment by [kwiesz91](https://answers.ros.org/users/23432/kwiesz91/) on 2015-09-14**:
To attempt an answer (I have yet to actually mess around with navigation, just reading a lot):  The costmap is stored in layers (with one of them being the obstacle layer), I believe that you can just get rid of the obstacle layer, if that's what you want.

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2015-09-14**:
You're right, I should keep it focused on the original question. I'll edit my answer to not have the question, but I have resolved the issue. Thanks for taking a look at it for me, kwiesz91!

**Comment by [songvanmino](https://answers.ros.org/users/30195/songvanmino/) on 2017-04-28**:
I have the same problem, I would like to ask you to solve it? How to solve?

**Comment by [pwong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3826/pwong/) on 2017-04-28**:
songvanmino, Did setting the param "allow_unknown: false" not do it for you?